# How to send parameters as string in alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift5

I must receive JSON data specifying a payload that I need to pass to a url. It will look like this:

```
{
  "token": "string",
  "body": {
    "token": "another string",
    "intValue": 1,
    "somethingElse": "another string"
  }
}
```

I know that *body* will have properties that are always, either a string or a number. But I don't know what the key will be that pairs with a valie of string or int.

I need to then send that body with Alamofire, which I was doing like this:

```
// parsing the data received with the Codable:
struct NotificationDetails: Codable {
    let token: String
    let body: [String:String]?
    let

    init (token: String) {
        self.token = token
        self.body = nil
    }

    init (token: String, body: [String:String]) {
        self.token = token
        self.body = body
    }

}
```

Note that I can't just use Alamofire's handy Parameters type like:

```
struct NotificationDetails: Codable {
    let token: String
    let body: Parameters?

    init (token: String) {
        self.token = token
        self.body = nil
    }

    init (token: String, body: Parameters) {
        self.token = token
        self.body = body
    }
}
```

because that is not codable, just like AnyObject.

```
// then elsewhere, using that data
guard let bodyJSON = localNotificationDetails.body else {
   callback()
   return
}
AF.request(url, method:method, parameters: bodyJSON).responseJSON(queue: queue) { response in
```

but now that I see that some of my data is going to be numeric instead of string, I'm wondering how I can do this now?

Answer (score 2):

Use  `bodyJson : [String : AnyObject]?`

example

```
let bodyJson = [
  "key" : "value",
  "key" : value,
"token": "string"
] as? [String : AnyObject]
```

Pass this type of data in json body request.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: bodyJson, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

                print(responseObject) 
}
```

you can perform other operations on `responseObject`

Comment: I can't do that -- the reason that I have a codable there is because I am decoding json to get that body. You can't have AnyObject in a Codable. I kinda need it to be a string.

Comment: https://medium.com/@JinwooChoi/passing-parameters-to-restful-api-with-swift-codable-d78eb78f7b1 may help you

Comment: So I figured out how to get a [String:AnyObject] from my json -- it was a lot of work but I have it. But I am getting `Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))` -- in the debugger, I can clearly see the object is just a small [String:AnyObject] of 1 init and two string values .. it looks good... it is iniitally declared as `var bodyJSON: [String:AnyObject]`